# Python array behaving weirdly

Tags: python, serial-port

I am using pyserial to read data off a serial port and sometimes the data I received behaves unexpectedly

Here is the important code

```
def getResponse():
    while ('\r' != rbuf[-1]):
        rbuf += s.read(s.inWaiting())
        print("b " + binascii.hexlify(rbuf))

    rbuf = rbuf.split('\r')
    rbuf = rbuf[:-1]
    print rbuf
    for char in rbuf:
        if(char == AFTER):
            print('a')
        elif(char == 'W'):
            print("Writing to the file")
        elif(char != ''):
            print char
            return char
    getResponse()
```

I understand that this isn't the best way to write the code, but somehting very stange happens.

When I receive the sequence ['a', 'A'] the value returned ends up being NONE.(which i check with a print statement elsewhere in the code

This does not happen when I receive ['W','a','A'] or when I recive ['A']

I figuired out a work around but I am really curious about this!!

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Due to indentation, you only appear to `return` in the case `elif(char != ''):`

Comment: I do only return in that case. (Hence the recursive call later if it doesn't work out)

Comment: So if that `elif` never executes, then you reach the end of the function without returning anything, so `None` gets returned implicitly. That's not too surprising to me.

Comment: In all other cases, then, you get `None`. Could you provide a complete [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the issue more clearly?

Comment: Sorry this is in the function GetResponse().
I tried making a "minimal example" but this was the best I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't entirely understand your code, but I strongly suspect that you want to `return` the result of the recursive `getResponse` call at the end of your function. If so, you need to explicitly `return`. Just calling the function won't do it for you.

```
getResponse()
```

Becomes

```
return getResponse()
```